# ensure that at least 2 items from 2 listview's (one in each listview) is selected with Jquery

Tags: jquery, asp.net, listview

in my website i have page with 2 listview's, each listview contain multiple div's and for each div i implement click event so i can change style to the chosen div. this is working fine, the next thing i want to do is to ensure that a least one item from each list view is selected, and if so than preform some action(i.e alert, redirect etc.) i have tried to use .each() and .find() but i end up with complicated and inefficient code. 
what is the best way to do this?
Here is my code:

```
<asp:ListView ID="ListView1" runat="server">
 <LayoutTemplate>
   <div id="itemPlaceholder" runat="server"></div> 
 </LayoutTemplate>
  <ItemTemplate>
         <div class="box" runat="server"></div> 
         <div class="selectedBox" runat="server"></div>
         <div class="box" runat="server"></div>
         <div class="box" runat="server"></div>
  </ItemTemplate>
</asp:ListView>
    <asp:ListView ID="ListView2" runat="server">
     <LayoutTemplate>
       <div id="itemPlaceholder" runat="server"></div> 
     </LayoutTemplate>
      <ItemTemplate>
             <div class="box" runat="server"></div> 
             <div class="selectedBox" runat="server"></div>
             <div class="box" runat="server"></div>
             <div class="box" runat="server"></div>
      </ItemTemplate>
    </asp:ListView>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        $(".box").click(function () {
        $(this).siblings().removeClass("selectedBox");
        $(this).addClass("selectedBox");
        });
    </script>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try something like this....

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  if ($("#listViewIDoption:selected").length<0)
    alert('select atLeast one item')
//do the rest
});
```